# Wordpress Redirection - Functions.php - Exclude Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have the following code inside my `functions.php` file, to provide a temporary redirect on my entire site (all URLs redirect to the homepage), but exclude the wordpress admin area...

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wa_redirect_site', 5 );
function wa_redirect_site(){    
    $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $current_post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
    if ( ! is_page(  )) { // Excludes page with this ID, and also the WordPress backend
        $id = get_the_ID();
        wp_redirect( 'https://wa-leicester.org.uk/', 302 ); // You can change 301 to 302 if the redirect is temporary
        exit;
    } 
}
```

So far, so good, BUT, I'm using a page builder called Bricks Builder, from within the Wordpress admin area, and the trouble is, when I create a template and try to then edit that template, it redirects to the homepage.

When editing a template, the URL it tried to access is: **.../template/115/?bricks=run**

Which gives me an ID, but I think I need to find a way to exclude the whole /template/ directory.

The code contains a way to exclude page IDs `is_page(  ))` so I have tried to add the directory to that, and I've also tried to see if something exists that replaces that such as: `is_directory` but I cant seem to find anything about it.

Any help would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: From the outside - if you try and visit any URL, it redirects to the homepage. Unless you're logged into wordpress, you can navigate around the admin area. I can edit pages in the page builder as it seems to direct to: .../?bricks=run but when I try and edit a template it directs to .../template/115/?bricks=run so I think the redirect is catching this and just sending me straight to the homepage - If I remove my block of code, the editor works fine...

Comment: I've edited my answer, it should redirect everything to the home page beside admin pages, the home page itself and ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_admin()` to determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page. The default WordPress customiser isn't considered an admin page.

Additionally a lot of plugins are using Ajax requests (@see [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)), so would want to filter that out.

By default, `wp_redirect` (cross-site) or `wp_safe_redirect` (locally) are returning a 302.

```php
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {  

    /**
     * Determines whether the current request is NOT for an administrative interface page NOR a WordPress Ajax request.
     * Determines whether the query is NOT for the blog homepage NOR for the front page of the site.
     * 
     * is_admin() returns true for Ajax requests, since wp-admin/admin-ajax.php defines the WP_ADMIN constant as true.
     * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/#comment-5755
     */
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! wp_doing_ajax() && ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        /**
         * Performs a safe (local) redirect, using wp_redirect().
         * 
         * By default the status code is set to 302.
         * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/#parameters
         */
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );

        exit;

    };

} );
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a much better way to do it, however when I add this code, it seems to break the site and I'm just getting a blank white page... Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot this `);` at the end ! Now been edited.

Comment: AH I played around with that, but couldn't see what was wrong! :) Thanks again, the redirect seems to be working perfectly, but its still redirecting this URL to the homepage: https://wa-leicester.org.uk/template/115/?bricks=run - for some reason...

Comment: Thing is plugins sometimes overwrite WordPress default behaviors, or are using bad practices to bypass some default function and we end up in situation like this one where a perfectly working piece of code that should do the job doesn't... you might want to add `! is_user_logged_in()` because I'm pretty sure you need to be logged-in to edit your stuff from your plugin. I've edited it once more.

Comment: Ah that seems to do the trick, thanks so much for the help. It's a theme and I'm using minimal plugins, but I guess the same still applies - the theme settings must be interfering!! Thanks again :)